# Nuxt Heroku Deployment Problem, It uses localhost instead of the website url

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, deployment, nuxt.js

This is my first time deploying a nuxt app to heroku, I've followed the instructions I've found on nuxt guide.

> Created the heroku app & added the following configuration:

[image]

> added the procfile with the following line: web:nuxt start

[image]

> And it worked, When I go to: https://coupongb-nuxt.herokuapp.com/ the website opened and the products are loaded but it seems the "infinit scrolling with uses $axios plugin isn't working, As well as opening a product page "by clicking a product card".
>
> So I guess it's $axios that's making that error, Seems it's baseURL is localhost:3000 istead of the website domain
> [image]

So my question is How to make this.$axios.$get(...) point to the website domain instead of localhost:300

Comment: NOTE: I'm using axios insite asyncData when the website main page first loads and it seems to works fine (it's base url is the website domain), but when using axios inside a method to load more products with infinit scrolling it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set environment variables for this. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Where ever you are configuring Axios have it look at the environment variable to set the baseURL, example:

```
Axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.APP_API
```

Then create your .env files in the root of your directory:

```
APP_API=https://coupongb-nuxt.herokuapp.com/
```

Alternatively you can change the baseurl inline whenever you are creating a call to your api. For example

```
this.$axios.get('/example-path')
```

would be replaced with

```
this.$axios({ url: '/example-path', baseURL: 'https://coupongb-nuxt.herokuapp.com' })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I'm sure this would work

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Tim´s response.

Add this at the top of your file:

```
const DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

This way DEV will be true if enviroment is for development and false if it´s for production.

Below inside your export default object, you add the axios object:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: development ? '' : 'https://your-heroku-url.com/'
  }
```

And thats it, this way you don´t have to write a URL and the base URL every time you use axios.